# Help needed in building MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables a and b. Table a has list of id like 1,2,3,4,5 etc and table b has their score like

```
1,20 
1,30 
1,40 
3,10
```

(20 30 40 10 are score while 1 and 3 are the id from table a) I want to calculate the average of the scores. i need the result should be like that:

```
average| id
-----------
20.45  |  1
30.15  |  2
60.45  |  3
```

Right now the average is not calculated it is just an example.

This is the query I am using right now but It is giving me only 1 result

QUERY:

```
select avg(score),id from b where id in (select id from a);
```

Please help me building the query.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `group by id` something like

```
select avg(score),id from b group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've explicitly added your "A" table in case there were other elements, such as person's names you wanted to get their info from...

```
select
      a.id,
      avg( b.score )
   from
      YourTableA a
         join YourTableB b
            on a.id = b.id
   group by
      a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
   select avg(score), a.id from a join b on a.id = b.id group by a.id;
```

Some useful links:

1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html
2. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in T-SQL... not 100% that this would work in MySQL but I think it will.

```
SELECT SUM(Score)/COUNT(Score) As 'Average', ID
FROM b
GROUP BY ID
```

However to get an answer back as a decimal you will probably have to do some casting of datatypes from int to long. This is how i would do it in SQL T-server... This will probably need some changing to work with MySQL but gives you an idea:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(SUM(Score) AS Decimal)/CAST(COUNT(Score) As Decimal)As Decimal(10,2)) As Average, ID
FROM b
GROUP BY ID
```

Hope this helps. I haven't USED AVG() because It gave me whole number results.